# Custom Form problem with formula to check duplicate values which are already in the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, formula

I have problem to solve simple formula. Custom form has many inputs, but I need check three of them if aren't this combination saved in the list already. If yes, need to show text with warning.

first input is a `text` value, second is one select from `lookup dropdown` input and last one is `number`

I created a `label` and I want add my formula to `visible` attribute:

```
If(LookUp(List, 'invoiceNumber:' = DataCardValue11.Text && 'supplierName' 
= DataCardValue26.Selected.Value && 'numberOfItems' = Value(DataCardValue21.text) ),true,false)
```

**Error**:

> invalid argument type Record

Is it even possible to check three different inputs from the saved data in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
CountRows(Filter(List, 'invoiceNumber:' = DataCardValue11.Text && 'supplierName'.Value = DataCardValue26.Selected.Value && 'numberOfItems' = Value(DataCardValue21.text))) > 0
```

**OR** something like this:

```
If(IsBlank(Lookup(List, 'invoiceNumber:' = DataCardValue11.Text && 'supplierName'.Value = DataCardValue26.Selected.Value && 'numberOfItems' = Value(DataCardValue21.text)).'invoiceNumber:'), false, true)
```

Where `Lookup(...).'invoiceNumber:'` should be non blank column value.

Comment: second formula works. thank you